# Handling Previous, Next and Done buttons for keyboard across UITableView custom cells

Tags: swift, uitableview

First of all, I'm a fairly new to Swift and I've been looking for a good solution to handle Previous, Next and Done buttons on a keyboard across different custom cells in UITableView.  I've looked at the various solutions on Stack Overflow but none of them fit 100% for what I need.

My tableview has one field (UITextField, UITextView, etc.) per row and need a generic way to move from one cell to the next.  Some of the solutions don't account for scenarios where the next cell might be offscreen.

I've come up with a solution which I'll post as an answer.  Feel free to comment on ways to improve if you have suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

Please check this library. Simple and effective. You just to need to install via cocoa pods and single line code in appDelegate

```
pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
```

https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

In App delegate

```
IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For my custom cells, I have a base class as a foundation since I'm creating everything programmatically.  It looks like this:

```
class BaseTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    weak var delegate: BaseTableViewCellDelegate? = nil
    var indexPath: IndexPath? = nil

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        setupViews()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func setupViews() {
        fatalError("BaseTableViewCell setupViews not overridden")
    }

    func handleBecomeFirstResponser() {
        // handle in derived class
    }

    func handleResignFirstResponder() {
        // handle in derived class
    }
}
```

Also, I've got a delegate for this base class that looks like this:

```
protocol BaseTableViewCellDelegate: class {
    func cellEdited(indexPath: IndexPath)
    func cellPreviousPressed(indexPath: IndexPath)
    func cellNextPressed(indexPath: IndexPath)
    func cellNeedsResize(indexPath: IndexPath)
}

// Using extension to provide default implementation for previous/next actions
//   This makes then optional for a cell that doesn't need them
extension BaseTableViewCellDelegate {
    func cellPreviousPressed(indexPath: IndexPath) {}
    func cellNextPressed(indexPath: IndexPath) {}
    func cellNeedsResize(indexPath: IndexPath) {}
}
```

I'm using an extension for a pure-swift mechanism to make the previous and next implementations optional in case we have a situation where we don't need these buttons.

Then, in my BaseTableViewCell class, I've got a function to setup the keyboard toolbar like this (below).  I've got another function to support a UITextView as well (there might be a better way to do this; not sure).

```
func setupKeyboardToolbar(targetTextField: UITextField, dismissable: Bool, previousAction: Bool, nextAction: Bool) {
    let toolbar: UIToolbar = UIToolbar()
    toolbar.sizeToFit()

    var items = [UIBarButtonItem]()
        let previousButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "previousArrowIcon"), style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
        previousButton.width = 30
        if !previousAction {
            previousButton.isEnabled = false
        } else {
            previousButton.target = self
            previousButton.action = #selector(toolbarPreviousPressed)
        }

        let nextButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "nextArrowIcon"), style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
        nextButton.width = 30
        if !nextAction {
            nextButton.isEnabled = false
        } else {
            nextButton.target = self
            nextButton.action = #selector(toolbarNextPressed)
        }

        items.append(contentsOf: [previousButton, nextButton])

    let spacer = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(dismissKeyboard))
    items.append(contentsOf: [spacer, doneButton])

    toolbar.setItems(items, animated: false)
    targetTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
}
```

Here are the associated action routines:

```
func toolbarPreviousPressed() {
    if delegate != nil && indexPath != nil {
        delegate?.cellPreviousPressed(indexPath: indexPath!)
    }
}

func toolbarNextPressed() {
    if delegate != nil && indexPath != nil {
        delegate?.cellNextPressed(indexPath: indexPath!)
    }
}
```

In my view controller where I have the tableview, my cellForRowAt function has this code:

```
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "textFieldCell") as! TextFieldCell
    let addressItem = (item as! XXXXXXAddressViewModelItem)
    cell.textField.placeholder = addressItem.placeHolderText
    cell.textField.text = addressItem.getValue(row: 0)
    cell.indexPath = indexPath
    cell.delegate = self
    cell.setupKeyboardToolbar(targetTextField: cell.textField, dismissable: true, previousAction: false, nextAction: true)
    return cell
```

Here is how I handle the delegate methods for the previous and next buttons being pressed:

```
func cellPreviousPressed(indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // Resign the old cell
    let oldCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! BaseTableViewCell
    oldCell.handleResignFirstResponder()

    // Scroll to previous cell
    let tempIndex = IndexPath(row: indexPath.row, section: indexPath.section - 1)
    tableView.scrollToRow(at: tempIndex, at: .middle, animated: true)

    // Become first responder
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: tempIndex) as! BaseTableViewCell
    cell.handleBecomeFirstResponser()
}

func cellNextPressed(indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // Resign the old cell
    let oldCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! BaseTableViewCell
    oldCell.handleResignFirstResponder()

    // Scroll to next cell
    let tempIndex = IndexPath(row: indexPath.row, section: indexPath.section + 1)
    self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: tempIndex, at: .middle, animated: true)

    // Become first responder for new cell
    let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: tempIndex) as! BaseTableViewCell
    cell.handleBecomeFirstResponser()
}
```

Finally, in my cell class derived from BaseTableViewCell, I override the handleBecomeFirstResponder and handleResignFirstResponder like so:

```
override func handleBecomeFirstResponder() {
    textField.becomeFirstResponder()
}

override func handleResignFirstResponder() {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

On a related note, I handle the keyboard show and hide notifications by using insets on the tableview:

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, (keyboardFrame?.height)!, 0)
self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, (keyboardFrame?.height)!, 0)
```

and:

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero
```

This took me a lot of trial-and-error to get this right and not seriously convolute my view controller with code that should be in the cell class.

I'm always looking for better ways to do this.  Let me know your thoughts!